# Refactor lambda expression to use Comparator.comparingDouble

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I have a the following lambda expression. My IDE (Intellij idea) tells me it should be replaced with `Comparator.comparingDouble` but I cannot find a way to do it.

```
List<javafx.stage.Screen> screenList = screens;

screenList.sort((screenA, screenB) -> Double.compare(
               screenA.getBounds().getMinX(), screenB.getBounds().getMinX()));
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with

```
screenList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(...));
```

or is this a false annotation from Intellij? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a function that converts `Screen` to `double`:

```
screenList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(screen -> screen.getBounds().getMinX()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij IDEA you just need to call quick fix at **compare** (pressing Alt+Enter) and click Enter at suggestion *replace with Comparator.comparing double*, IDEA will do the replacement automatically.

```
screenList.sort((screenA, screenB) -> Double.com<ALTENTER_HERE>pare(
            screenA.getBounds().getMinX(), screenB.getBounds().getMinX()));
```

code will be replaced with:

```
 screenList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(screenA -> screenA.getBounds().getMinX()));
```